# Duplicating a project and showing for all users (Outsystems)

Tags: outsystems

I'm new to Outsystems and I'm doing a project for university and I'm having some problems creating a project.

Explaining the problem, as it appears in the image sent as attachments, when I click on the "Add Project" button I want to create a card containing the data seen in the print (Projects data). The problem is that, first of all, data is showing up for all profiles and not just for the profile I'm adding. Second, instead of creating another project, you are editing the existing one, with this theres no new card added.

Unfortunately I can't send the oml file. If you can help without that, that would be perfect.

I apologize in advance for future kind of stupid questions, but it's because I'm new to Outsystems.

And ignore the non-existent design :D .

Here is the main page where i want to display the projects added.
[image]

Here is the popup form that appears after pressing the button "Add project".
[image]

Here is the action from the button "save" from the form.
[image]

At last, here is the content from the page.

[image]
[image]

If needed i can show more information.